# track agent movement in anylogic

Tags: simulation, anylogic, agent-based-modeling

I am running a pedestrian simulation in Anylogic and want greater granularity in the agent position information that I get at the end of my model. Currently, I have it set up to show a heat map of traffic density, but I would like to trace the actual position of each agent through its time in the model, like a line or trail.

model visualization at the end of a simulation
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwCVo.png

Answer (score 0):

Add a cyclic event into your Pedestrian agent type (you cannot use the default pedestrians but must create your own agent type).

Then, every second (or whatever resolution you need), write the pedestrian coordinates (`getX` and `getY`) into a dbase table along with its index.

Then, you can do any post-processing that you need.

PS: typically, this is not really necessary, so make sure you *really* need this ;)